# Getting user_likes on facebook sdk ios

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

Im requesting to have access to the user's likes but I can't find a snippet to actually have access to that.
Here's how I request access to the user's likes (Im also requesting persmission to post on his behalf):

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"publish_actions",
                        @"user_likes",
                        nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];
```

Which and a AlertView pops up showing that Im asking for user likes and publish permissions, but then on the callback I can't read the likes in the `NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user` that is sent to me, is only contains the basic profile info.

```
  if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
       NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
       NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"%@", user);
         }
       }
  }
```

Any ideas to get the user likes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/posts?fields=likes" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSArray *myLikes = (NSArray*)[result data];
    // Do something with myLikes
}];
```

Use myLikes writeToFile: as a *.plist to check out how the data is organized. Hope this helps.